# Frame names being assigned automatically

Tags: delphi

What's so special with Frames that when you create them run-time it gets assigned a name automatically ? This causes a problem when you use them in a loop i.e. :

```
for i := 0 to 3 do
  TMyFrame.Create(self); //Error on 2nd pass
```

On first pass, the frame is explicityl named 'MyFrame'.
On second pass, it will try to name it again 'MyFrame' which
obivously will cause an exception as there is already a 
component with such name.

The other components or forms are happy to be created without
me assigning them a name. What gives ?

This is on Delphi 2006 btw.

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

If you are using TFrame to create your Frame, then it wont raise that error.

i.e., If your code looks like this, you wont have any problems

```
for i := 0 to 3 do 
  Frame1 := TFrame.Create(self);
```

because here the Name property is unassigned. If you want you can check by using the statement `ShowMessage(Frame1.Name);`

But if you use TMyFrame i.e., the frame which you derived from TFrame, then it will giving the problem.

I think the reason is, Delphi was explicitly assigning the same Name every time you create the TMyName.

Comment: thank you for clarifying this -- I was sooo sleepy ;-) very good answer!!

Answer (score 1):

you're trying to create the same frame 4 times, each time you create the frame it will have the same name, one way to avoid is

```
...
var
  i: Integer;
  lFrame: TFrame;
begin
  for i := 0 to 3 do begin
    lFrame := TFrame.Create(Self);
    // assign a unique name to the frame
    lFrame.Name := Format('MyFrame%d', [i]);
    // set the parent, align, etc...
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I believe his question is _why_ he has to do this with frames, when he doesn't have to do it with other components.

Comment: I get that Dorin. I'm sure there are ways around it. 
But the question is why ? Delphi is fine with this :

for i := 0 to 5 do
  TButton.Create(self);

Comment: because the frame is a descendent of your custom class?!

Comment: I think it should also work to set the name to an empty string (but I have not tested it.

Comment: Yes it works when you set it to an empty string, this is what I usually do to work around this.

Answer (score 0):

Co-incidentally I just bumped into this myself (again).

If you take the name out of your frame component then Delphi moans that "Root Component must have a name" - I guess it because somewhere Delphi is calling `RegisterClass(RootComponentName)` and then to create it (or a descendent) it's calling `Findclass(RootComponentName)` or similar. As you can do this yourself to create components that you don't actually know the classname of a design time, why would Delphi not do the same?

Whereas with a TButton etc. it is already a registered Class.